# how to write a SQL to display distinct values of two columns in one row

Tags: sql, window-functions, hana, full-outer-join

I have tables a,b.
Table a

```
ID     In
----------------
1      Mat1
1      Mat2
2      Mat1
3      Mat3
```

Table b

```
ID      Out
--------------
 1      Mat4
 2      Mat4
 2      Mat5
 3      Mat6
```

I want a result like below.

```
ID     In    Out
------------------
 1    Mat1   Mat4
 1    Mat1
 2    Mat1   Mat4
 2           Mat5
 3    Mat3   Mat6
```

I think full join can't make empty field in some row.Maybe I need to use Rownum for this? Any help? Thx.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: Display what you have.

Comment: Should the second row in the result not be ID 1 - In *Mat2* - Out ‘’ ?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows, and then `full join` the results. For this to really make sense, you would need a column in each table to order the records. I assumed `ordering_id`:

```
select id, a.in, b.out
from (
    select a.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by ordering_id) rn 
    from tablea a
) a
full join (
    select b.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by ordering_id) rn 
    from tableb b
) b using(id, rn)
```

Not all database support `full join`s (and not all of them support `using()` for join conditions).

A more portable approach is to use `union all`:

```
select id, max(in) in, max(out) out
from (
    select id, in, null out, row_number() over(partition by id order by ordering_id) rn 
    from tablea
    union all
    select id, null, out, row_number() over(partition by id order by ordering_id) rn 
    from tableb b
) x
group by id, rn
```